# how to add a reference in non-standard format to a LaTeX bibtex file?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, cross-referencing

I would like to add this reference in Latex, could someone kindly help? How could I add it using bibtex?

National Highway Traffic Safety Administration, ``Development of an FCW Algorithm Evaluation Methodology with Evaluation of Three Alert Algorithms”, Performed by The Johns Hopkins University Applied Physics Laboratory, Contract No: DTFH61-99-C-00051, Washington, DC., Tech. Rep. DOT HS 811 145, 2009.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use BibTeX, here's my suggestion:

A quick Google Scholar search comes up with this entry:

```
@article{mclaughlin2009development,
  title={Development of an FCW algorithm evaluation methodology with evaluation of three alert algorithms},
  author={McLaughlin, Shane B and Hankey, Jonathan M and Dingus, Thomas A and Klauer, Sheila G},
  journal={National Highway Traffic Safety Administration, Tech. Rep},
  year={2009}
}
```

Which doesn't include the details you have noted, and so for tech reports I prefer this format with institution and notes...

```
@techreport{FCWevaluation,
  title={{Development of an FCW Algorithm Evaluation Methodology with Evaluation of Three Alert Algorithms}},
  author={McLaughlin, Shane B and Hankey, Jonathan M and Dingus, Thomas A and Klauer, Sheila G},
  year={2009},
  institution={National Highway Traffic Safety Administration},
  note={Johns Hopkins University Applied Physics Laboratory, Contract No: DTFH61-99-C-00051, Washington, DC., Tech. Rep. DOT HS 811 145}
}
```

Notice that I "protect" the title from goofy changes (like changing FCW to Fcw) by using double braces.